# How to relate two unrelated classes so they can be used in abstract class for same method

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have two json schema files from which two classes have been generated using jackson-
CarSearchResponse, and HomeSearchResponse. They are not related.

In my implementation, I have created an abstract class with common functionality, and then created two concrete implementation for Car and Home.

```
abstract class SearchResponseFlow {
    void execute() {
        responseFlow.map(response);
    }

    abstract ResponseWrapper<SearchResponse> getData(); // SearchResponse is imaginary, what change can I make to make it accept both CarSearchResponse and HomeSearchResponse.
}

class HomeSearchResponseFlow extends SearchResponseFlow {
    void map(HomeSearchResponse resp) {
        // logic
    }

    ResponseWrapper<HomeSearchResponse> getData() {
        // logic
    }
}

class CarSearchResponseFlow extends SearchResponseFlow {
    void map(CarSearchResponse resp) {
        // logic
    }

ResponseWrapper<CarSearchResponse> getData() {
        // logic
    }
}
```

`SearchResponse` is imaginary as both CarSearchResponse and HomeSearchResponse do not implement SearchResponse since both are separately generated from different JSON schema files, what change can I make to make it accept both CarSearchResponse and HomeSearchResponse.
I have to consume *SearchResponse outside also, so what can be done?

Comment: Assuming `HomeSearchResponse` etc implements `SearchResponse`, you can just do `ResponseWrapper<? extends SearchResponse>`. You should also change the `getData` methods in the subclasses to return `ResponseWrapper<? extends SearchResponse>`

Comment: use generic abstract class SearchResponseFlow<T extends SearchResponse> { abstract ResponseWrapper<T> getData();}

Comment: SearchResponse is imaginary as both CarSearchResponse and HomeSearchResponse do not implement SearchResponse since both are separately generated from different JSON schema files,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with Generics:

```
class ResponseWrapper<T>{

}
class HomeSearchResponse {
}

class CarSearchResponse {
}
```

---

```
abstract class SearchResponseFlow<T> {

    public void execute(T response) {
        System.out.println(response);
    }

    abstract ResponseWrapper<T> getData();
}
```

---

```
class HomeSearchResponseFlow extends SearchResponseFlow<HomeSearchResponse> {

    @Override
    public void execute(HomeSearchResponse homeSearchResponse) {
        System.out.println(homeSearchResponse);
    }

    @Override
    ResponseWrapper<HomeSearchResponse> getData() {
        return new ResponseWrapper<>();
    }

}
```

---

```
class CarSearchResponseFlow extends SearchResponseFlow<CarSearchResponse> {

    @Override
    public void execute(CarSearchResponse carSearchResponse) {
        System.out.println(carSearchResponse);
    }

    @Override
    ResponseWrapper<CarSearchResponse> getData() {
        return new ResponseWrapper<>();
    }
}
```